# WebView problem

Tags: cocoa, macos

My program  have two classes, first of them is regular app delegate `NSObject`. The second one is a `NSWindowController` subclass with NSWindow and WebView on it, which shows html page from application bundle.

Here is how i call window from AppDelegate:

```
-(IBAction)showWebViewForm:(id)sender
{
    webViewForm = [[WebViewForm alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"WebViewForm"];
    [webViewForm showWindow:self];
}
```

Here is how i render the webpage in `WebViewForm : NSWindowController`:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib{
    [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
    [webview setUIDelegate: self];
    [webview setResourceLoadDelegate: self];
    [webview setPolicyDelegate:self];
    [webview setFrameLoadDelegate:self];

    [[webview mainFrame] loadRequest:
     [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
      [NSURL fileURLWithPath:
       [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"data"]]]];

}
```

It's work fine, but only for the first time. When i close `WebViewForm` window and reopen it, webpage is disappearing from WebView. Why is so that, and how to fix it?

**UPD** Even if embed `awakeFromNib` code in special new method like `-(void)refreshWebview` and then call `[webViewForm refreshWebview]` right after `[webViewForm showWindow:self];`, still — page loads only for first time, and it's really weird ( Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I figure it out by myself. The problem was, that webview closed when it's parent window closed. So, there is special method for case like that:

`[webview setShouldCloseWithWindow:NO];`